# How to measure how long it take's for a laptop's battery to charge

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, battery-life

I have the following scenario:

I am testing several laptops with Windows 8.1 installed. One of the tests is to measure how much the battery lasts. For this task I use benchmarks like PeaceKeeper or PowerMark.

I also want to measure how long it takes for the battery to charge itself to 100% after it gets depleted. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use external tools, you could tap the power (pun intended) of WMI queries and WMI Eventing. 
Simple query to run from command line:

```
wmic path win32_battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining
```

will give you estimated charge. Now, to get repeated readings you could just put it in a timed loop, but there is a better (or fancier :-) way: register a battery event and a handler for it - here it is done in Powershell 
(start Powershell and paste/exec those two commands):

```
$action={get-wmiobject -computername localhost -Query "Select * from Win32_Battery"|% {write-host battery charge: ($_.EstimatedChargeRemaining) time:  $(get-date)}}

Register-WMIEvent -query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Battery'" -messageData "battery charge" -sourceIdentifier "battery" -action $action
```

This will produce a line of output at your Powershell console each time an event is raised. Here is the output from my laptop:

> battery charge: 67 time: 2014-12-11 17:59:53
>   battery charge: 68 time: 2014-12-11 18:00:23
>   battery charge: 69 time: 2014-12-11 18:01:23
>   battery charge: 70 time: 2014-12-11 18:01:53
>   battery charge: 71 time: 2014-12-11 18:02:53
>   battery charge: 72 time: 2014-12-11 18:03:23
>   battery charge: 73 time: 2014-12-11 18:04:23
>   battery charge: 74 time: 2014-12-11 18:05:14
>   battery charge: 75 time: 2014-12-11 18:06:04
>   battery charge: 76 time: 2014-12-11 18:06:44

My simple action is just a console message, but you could of course do whatever you like - for example write it out to file

(note: I think WMI counter goes to 99 which is shown as 100%/full at the status bar - so it's 1% 'behind' the display)

Comment: That's a neat trick. WMI comes in handy for a lot of stuff. If only it were easy to learn. Are you aware of any good places to start learning about it? +1 to you.

Comment: @Vinayak MSDN has quite a lot of information, see here for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Related so question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896188/good-resources-to-learn-wmi-in-net

Comment: When I run wmic path win32_battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining, I get 4 as the result. What does that mean? How do you interpret the results?

Comment: @CorporateGeek This should be percentage: EstimatedChargeRemaining

    Data type: uint16
    Access type: Read-only

    Estimate of the percentage of full charge remaining (full class reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Mmm... wmic path win32_battery get EstimatedChargeRemaining is not useful then. It tells me how much charge the battery has. I need to measure exactly how long it takes for a battery to charge from empty to 100%.

Comment: @CorporateGeek Start from discharged log it till it's fully charged, calculate time difference. (there is BatteryRechargeTime, but it's not supported)

Answer (score 1):

[Battery Eater](http://batteryeater.com/about.html) supports creating a battery charging graph.

[image: Battery Eater]

It also logs the current battery capacity every 30 seconds during a discharge benchmark. I suppose it also logs this information while creating the charging graph.

Here's a snippet of the discharge log:

```
Log started: 13-01-2014 20:15:43
===============================================================================
[20:16:13]  36680   0
[20:16:43]  36630   0
[20:17:13]  36590   0
[20:17:43]  36530   0
[20:18:13]  36490   0
[20:18:43]  36430   0
[20:19:13]  36370   0
[20:19:43]  36320   0
[20:20:13]  36280   0
[20:20:43]  36220   0
[20:21:13]  36170   0
[20:21:43]  36110   0
...
[17:52:38]  2080    0
[17:53:08]  2250    0
[17:53:38]  2410    0
===============================================================================
Log ended: 14-01-2014 17:53:45
```

To open the `BEG` files it generates, [drag-and-drop them into the Battery Eater executable file](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/benchmark-laptops-battery-life-battery-eater/). Also, since this is pretty old software, you may need to run it in Compatibility mode.

Comment: Where is that BEG file generated? Where do you find it?

Comment: The `BEG` files are generated in the same folder as `BEPro.exe`. The folder names correspond to the current date, so if you did a benchmark today, they's be named `15_12_2014_1`, `15_12_2014_2`, `15_12_2014_3` etc. The `BEG` files are located inside these folders along with the log file.